# javascript showing up as text on my HTML page

Tags: javascript

Greetings all: Here is my simple code, Why is my javascript showing up as text on my page? any help would greatly appreciated, also any tips would be appreciated. thank you in advance

```
<html>
<head><title>jsn massage - home page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "images/100_0350a.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "images/circle.jpg"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "images/AddisonStudioI.jpg"

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/100_0350a.jpg" name="slide" width="400" height="400>
<script type="text/javascript">

var step=1;
function slideit()
{
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src");
if(step<3)
step++;
else
step=1;
setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);
}
slideit();
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="images/100_0350a.jpg" name="slide" width="400" height="400>
```

You should properly close this.

```
<img src="images/100_0350a.jpg" name="slide" width="400" height="400" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put a closing quote on `height="400"`

```
<img src="images/100_0350a.jpg" name="slide" width="400" height="400"/>
```

Comment: wow... thank you so much!! I knew it had to be something stupid like that. it always takes someone else to notice.

Answer (score 1):

Your height attribute is missing the closing quotation mark and the img tag should be closed properly.

```
<img src="images/100_0350a.jpg" name="slide" width="400" height="400"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in css

`script { display: none !important; }`